# Solr: Day of week, second of day with timezones

Tags: datetime, solr, timezone

We require to search by **day of week** and **time of day** using **SOLR**.

That`s why we first convert date to UTC and then create two index fields: UTC second of day and UTC day of week.
We know what timezone user requests, so we are able to shift this required values and create query:

> Monday from 4:00 to 6:00 AM in +5 timezone

is converted to search values for UTC:

> (Sunday from 23:00 to 24:00) OR Monday (0:00 to 1:00)

Unfortunatelly this query will fail in timezones with daylight saving time, when timezone is shifted  +5 is +6.

Is there a way how to query by correct time of day?

Only solution we could think of is add to query also date ranges, which were in summer/winter time:
((Sunday from 23:00 to 24:00) OR Monday (0:00 to 1:00)) AND (30.10.2015 TO 27.3.2016) OR Monday (0:00 to 2:00)) AND (27.3.2015 TO 30.10.2015 ) OR ... OR ... , 
where these ... represents date, when was switched from summer to winter time.

Data may be recorded in any timezone and viewed in any timezone as well